# How do I execute the function public method declared inside a class which is in turn inside a private method?

Tags: java, object, inner-classes

So, I want to execute the sum() of the following block of code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class LocalOuterClass {  // start of outer
    private int x = 10;
    private Object run() {  //start of inner
        class LocalInnerClass {
            private int y = 20;
            public void sum() {
                System.out.println(x+y);
            }
        }   //end of inner
        LocalInnerClass lc = new LocalInnerClass();
        //lc.sum();
        return lc;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalOuterClass Loc = new LocalOuterClass();
        Object obj = Loc.run();
        System.out.println(obj.getClass());
        Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            String MethodName = method.getName(); 
            System.out.println("Name of the method: "+ MethodName);
        }
    }
}   //end of outer
```

When I do lc.sum(), the sum() is correctly executed. But when I'm returning an object of the inner class to the main() and try to execute sum(), it gives a compiler error. Doing getClass().getMethods() on the object does print sum() as one of the methods. What should I do to execute the sum() inside main()?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change return type to `LocalInnerClass` and move `LocalInnerClass` out of the method:

```
public class LocalOuterClass {

    private int x = 10;

    private class LocalInnerClass {

        private int y = 20;

        public void sum() {
            System.out.println(x + y);
        }
    }

    private LocalInnerClass run() {
        LocalInnerClass lc = new LocalInnerClass();
        //lc.sum();
        return lc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalOuterClass Loc = new LocalOuterClass();
        LocalInnerClass obj = Loc.run();

        obj.sum();  // it works!
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the whole `LocalInnerClass` is not known to your `main`-method. It does not help, that it has a public method, if the whole type is unknown. You need to refactor your code in order to change that.

Actually your method `run` currently returns a value of type `Object` and you'd need to return a value of type `LocalInnerClass`, however this is not possible due to type visibility.

There are basically two options you have. One is to move the whole `LocalInnerClass` to a location that is visible to `main` (like oleg.cherednik suggested):

```java
class LocalOuterClass {
    private int x = 10;
    private LocalInnerClass run() {  // now we can retun `LocalInnerClass`
        return new LocalInnerClass();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LocalOuterClass().run().sum(); // works!
    }
    
    private class LocalInnerClass {
        private int y = 20;
        public void sum() {
            System.out.println(x+y);
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to implement/extend a different type that has `sum`, e.g. like this:

```java
class LocalOuterClass { 
    private int x = 10;
    private Summable run() {  //start of inner
        class LocalInnerClass implements Summable {
            private int y = 20;
            public void sum() {
                System.out.println(x+y);
            }
        } 
        return new LocalInnerClass();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LocalOuterClass().run().sum(); // works as well
    }
    
    private interface Summable {
        void sum();
    }
}
```

With this interface-option the type `LocalInnerClass` is still not visible to anyone outside your `run`-method, however the `Summable`-interface is and since your `LocalInnerClass` implements `Summable` you can return a value of that type.